# Visual Studio Code Java: Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a maven project that I import in Visual Studio Code that uses the following extentions:
Java Language Support by Red hat.

Our project is still built on Java 8, and although I know we should upgrade, this is where we are right now. Because VS Code requires at least JDK 11 to run properly, I also have it installed. These are my settings.json:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true
},
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "disabled",
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\OpenJDK\\openjdk-11.0.12_7",
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_211",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-11",
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\OpenJDK\\openjdk-11.0.12_7",
    }
  ]
}
```

I can run our .war file through VS Code's Tomcat plugin perfectly, but I can't run my junit tests because of a problem:

[image]

(The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project.)

I know this must be JRE related, but I can't figure out how to solve it.
I think this because of: [Visual Studio Code Cannot Handle Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103869/visual-studio-code-cannot-handle-java)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Download and Install](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install) from the JUnit 4's official website for the getting started documentation.

JUnit5 in `Maven` please refer to [this guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven), and [junit-platform-console-standalone.jar](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.junit.platform%20AND%20a:junit-platform-console-standalone) is needed in no build tools project.

Check if you missed dependencies or jars mentioned above.

Comment: I do have the JUnit dependency in my pom.xml. In Eclipse the project works fine, and a mvn clean install also builds ok! Thanks though :)